# React Shared Component/Caching

Tags: javascript, parsing, web, reactjs

I have a React component that pulls some data from a Parse database and displays it. However, this component is shared across pages, and everytime I switch pages the component fetches the data again. Is there a React or Parse paradigm in place where I can cache this data or reuse the same component and prevent it from reloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch the data further up the hierarchy and pass as props.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do this with my current structure. I have a header component within a page component. This page component takes in a react component as a child and wraps it in a header and a footer. I have two web pages, a home page and an about page that use the page component. Even at that level, if I were to fetch the data there, navigating between those two pages re-renders the entire component and its children, leaving me with the same problem. I feel like passing down the data to the home/about pages is wrong - I made the page wrapper so I wouldn't need to worry about duplication

Comment: If the Parse data is held at the non changing component then even with the pages re-rendering the data will be the same. This is what props are suited for. Even if you were using a flux pattern the store for that data would be given to the highest component for which children shared that data. Otherwise you could cache the data on the server but that is not best practice for performance and tracking would be problematic.